# javascript function that uses jquery isn't being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm woking on a ASP.NET project and im trying to use the attr function,
when im putting in the script tag the src for the jquery file the function isnt being called when im calling it via c# code.

```
 <script type ="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function startGame(path) {
            alert(path);
            $("#test").attr("style", "color:Blue");
            $("#game_param").attr("value", path);
            $("#game_embed").attr("src", path);
        }
    });   
</script>
```

I tried to write a simple javascript fucntion

```
<script type ="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js">
    function startGame(a) {
        alert(a);
    }
</script>
```

and it wasn't called either

im getting en error that startGame isn't defined, in both cases.
can someone expain to me what im doing wrong?

Comment: show the code where you call the function.... just defining it willl not call the function..

Comment: Try including the jQuery script on a separate line. `<script type ="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>` and then put your script after it `<script>$(document).ready(.....);</script>`

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the jQuery source separately from your custom code. Otherwise I believe what is inside of the script tag is ignored.

```
 <script type ="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var p = 'here/is/my/path';
    function startGame(path) {
        alert(path);
        $("#test").attr("style", "color:Blue");
        $("#game_param").attr("value", path);
        $("#game_embed").attr("src", path);
    }
    startGame(p);
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: do you have any ideas why it still wont alert?

Comment: I've updated my answer. You probably need to call startGame within the document.ready function.

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript isn't correct.

When you do:

```
<script type ="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js">
  function startGame(a) {
    alert(a);
  }
</script>
```

You're setting the source of the JavaScript file to be the jQuery JS file. If you want to define your own functions, you have to put it in its own `script` tag, like so:

```
<script type ="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function startGame(a) {
        alert(a);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually have multiple errors.

1. Browsers will ignore any javascript written inside a `script` tag that has a `src` attribute. So you need to include jQuery separately, like so:

   ```
   <script type ="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
   <script>
       // Your code here.
   </script>
   ```
2. You're never actually calling the function, only declaring them. If you're only going to use this once, you don't even need a function:

   ```
   <script type ="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
           alert(path);
           $("#test").attr("style", "color:Blue");
           $("#game_param").attr("value", path);
           $("#game_embed").attr("src", path);
       });
   </script>
   ```

   Otherwise, you need to call the function after declaring it like so:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       function startGame(path) {
           // Your code
       }
       startGame();
   });
   ```

[Function Declarations vs Expressions](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/)

Comment: im calling them via c#

Comment: Can you please provide your C# code? If mine and the other answers here didn't help, it might not be a problem in the JS.